# What should I do with possible frostbite: Swollen feet after putting them in warm water

Tags: health, feet, frostbite

My feet were frostbite, so I put my feet in hot water when I got home. Ice was forming in my shoe. After I put my feet in the water they puffed up A LOT, they were badly swollen!!! Should I get medical help? I can't bend my feet because they're so badly swollen!

Comment: Yup. Get medical attention asap.

Comment: Questions asking for medical advice are not really good to answer in this Q&A format, especially when related to problems that would require more or less immediate reaction. You surely should get qualified medical advice as soon as possible.

Comment: @BenediktBauer, couldn't this be useful? Your right, if I had this problem, my first reaction would be to contact the doctor not write a question here! But if a good answer is added here, anyone in the future searching for an answer to this may find this information useful. PS, **Get medical attention**.

Comment: @BenediktBauer I agree that when an immediate answer is required, posting a question here doesn't make sense. But as Liam pointed out, answering the question will help others in similar situations. No harm in having the question here. If you still feel unsatisfied, please close the question so that others can air their opinion on the same.

Comment: @Unsung My comment was not intended as "This question is really really bad, we should close it and definitely not answer it" but more like some educational impulse to raise some sensitivity about the problems around medical questions.

Comment: Happened to me (having ice in my shoe). Got lucky to keep my toes. Now I carry **frostbite dressing (good also for burns, light and cheep, very easy to apply)** and gaiter in winter in the mountains.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you should seek medical expertise.

From [healthcentral.com](http://www.healthcentral.com/encyclopedia/408/453.html):

> When the skin has thawed and rewarming is complete, cover the damaged
>   skin with bandages and warm clothing. **Contact your doctor or go to an
>   emergency room**.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to PPL's answer. The UK National Health Service has good practical advice on this also. It's available [here](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Frostbite/Pages/Treatment.aspx). But to summarise some of the relevant points:

> Treatment for frostbite depends on how severe your symptoms are. You
>   should always seek medical attention if you suspect you or someone
>   else has frostbite.
>
> If symptoms are severe, go immediately to your nearest accident and
>   emergency department

---

> The affected areas need to be re-warmed. Do not try to do this until
>   you are out of the cold. If the warming process is started and the
>   frozen parts are re-exposed to the cold, it can cause further
>   irreversible damage.
>
> Re-warming should be done under medical supervision because:
>
> - it can be a painful process that requires access to painkillers and    expert medical assessment
> - the best results are achieved using a whirlpool bath that contains a mild antiseptic
>
> ### Severe frostbite
>
> In cases of severe frostbite, you will need to be admitted to a
>   specialist unit that has experience in treating these sorts of
>   injuries.
>
> This is often a specialist burns unit, as exposure to very high
>   temperatures can cause the same sort of injury as exposure to very
>   cold temperatures.